# Simulate the multi-thread process of task T by using Future Class

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, future

Here is a task T:
T is composed of many subtasks, and the completion time of each subtask is different.
If one of the subtasks fail, the others should be stoped at once and the task T will fail.

So how to simulate the process of task T? (require fast-failure)
Maybe Future Class could solve it. But how?

Comment: Do the sub-tasks run in parallel, or not? In parallel means they all run at the same time. Not in parallel means that the second sub-task cannot start until the first sub-task completes and the third sub-task cannot start until the second sub-task completes and so on.

Comment: Yes, the subtasks run in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give a simulation example by using CompletableFuture
I create a Task Class TaskT, make it looks more real. And the Task Class contains three `state`, `runTask()` method and `cancel()` method.

- Three state are `Success`, `Cancelling` and `Cancelled`.Success means task run completed.Cancelling means task is cancelling. Cancelled means the task has been Cancelled, advice others task cancel quickly.
- `runTask() method`: I use `Thread.sleep(interval)` to simulate runing state. And when the task run finish, the code `if(cancelled) return Result.CANCELLED;` detect whether the state is canceled?
- `cancel() method`: I use double-check lock to decorate the "cancel" logic to ensure it is single instance.

Finally, in the main metod, I use `CompletableFuture` Class to start thread and return param. `thenAccept()` method is useful and help SUCCESS TASK advice the other RUNNING TASKs cancel the task.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Competable {

    // three state after run task
    static enum Result{
        SUCCESS, FAIL, CANCELLED
    }

    // task list
    static List<TaskT> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Task List
     */
    public static class TaskT{
        private String name;
        private int timeInSecond;
        private Result ret;

        volatile boolean cancelling = false;
        volatile boolean cancelled = false;

        public TaskT(String name, int timeInSecond, Result ret){
            this.name = name;
            this.timeInSecond = timeInSecond * 1000;
            this.ret = ret;
        }

        /**
         * Simulate task runing
         * runing time in real work is uncertain
         * maybe run in computing，maybe run in IO
         */
        public Result runTask(){
            int interval = 100;
            int total = 0;
            try {
                for(;;){
                    Thread.sleep(interval);
                    total += interval;
                    if(total>=timeInSecond) break;
                    if(cancelled) return Result.CANCELLED;

                }
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(name + "Task End!!!");

            return ret;
        }

        /**
         * Simlulate task cancel
         * and set cancel time
         */
        public void cancel() {
            if (!cancelled) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (cancelled) return;
                    cancelling = true;
                    System.out.println(name + "cancelling!!!");
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println(name + "cancelled!!!");
                }
                cancelled = true;
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * rollback: advice the other thread cancel
     */
    public static void callback(Result result, TaskT task){
        if(Result.FAIL == result){
            for(TaskT _task : tasks){
                if(_task!=task){
                    _task.cancel();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TaskT subtask1 = new TaskT("task1", 3, Result.SUCCESS);
        TaskT subtask2 = new TaskT("task2", 4, Result.SUCCESS);
        TaskT subtask3 = new TaskT("task3", 1, Result.FAIL);

        tasks.add(subtask1);
        tasks.add(subtask2);
        tasks.add(subtask3);

        for(TaskT task:tasks){
            CompletableFuture f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->task.runTask())
                    .thenAccept((result -> callback(result, task)));
        }

        // System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix to this is to separate out these Runnables into their own threadpool so you can then call `shutdownNow()` on that pool only which interrupts all of the tasks in that pool

Comment: I think you need to [edit] your answer and post some code demonstrating how to create a "thread pool" using `ExecutorService`, how to add tasks to the service and how to invoke method `shutdownNow()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using FutureTask.

One of the tasks simulates failure by waiting for 1 second and then cancelling the other tasks. Even though they are waiting for 5 seconds, the program completes in 1 second.

You would need to wrap your Runnable in something like this which can cancel if the actual task fails.

To be able to cancel a task, it needs to be in a state where Thread.interrupt() will stop the thread. If it is just sitting in a loop, for instance, then the Future will be cancelled (so get() will return immediately), but the task itself will keep running.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FutureTaskExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<FutureTask<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            final int ii = i;
            FutureTask<String> task =
                    new FutureTask<>(new Callable<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String call() throws Exception {
                            if (ii == 9) {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                tasks.subList(0,9).stream().forEach(t -> t.cancel(true));
                                return "Failure";
                            } else {
                                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                                System.out.println("Task " + ii + " slept for " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
                                return "Completed";
                            }
                        }
                    });
            tasks.add(task);
            executorService.execute(task);
        }
        List<String> results = tasks.stream().map(t -> {
            try {
                return t.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Interrupted";
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Completed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " " + results);
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Done in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code really works, it is great. And more, I think it is not graceful enough. In my opinion, the task shoud be adviced by task run success or fail but not be adviced by client.

Comment: This is just a sketch to show how this sort of thing can be done with FutureTask. Absolutely your task shouldn’t be responsible for canceling the other tasks, the client task should be wrapped by a framework task which knows how to detect failure, and does the cancels.